# How to run the VBA Excel to JSON for multiple reports?

Tags: json, vba, excel

I have a Excel Macro that generates monthly reports for multiple clients. I got this code from someone else's question([Is it possible in VBA convert Excel table to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100193/is-it-possible-in-vba-convert-excel-table-to-json)) that was asked here but the code runs only 1 time and generates 1 file every time with the same name. I want to convert the excel sheet into JSON so that i can upload it to Azure Blob.

```
Sub export_in_json_format()

Dim fs As Object
Dim jsonfile
Dim rangetoexport As Range
Dim rowcounter As Long
Dim columncounter As Long
Dim linedata As String

' change range here
Set rangetoexport = Sheet2.Range("a2:b6")

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' change dir here

Set jsonfile = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Satwant\Desktop\" & "MonthlyReport.json", True)


linedata = "{""Output"": ["
jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
For rowcounter = 2 To rangetoexport.Rows.Count
    linedata = ""
    For columncounter = 1 To rangetoexport.Columns.Count
        linedata = linedata & """" & rangetoexport.Cells(1, columncounter) & """" & ":" & """" & rangetoexport.Cells(rowcounter, columncounter) & """" & ","
    Next
    linedata = Left(linedata, Len(linedata) - 1)
    If rowcounter = rangetoexport.Rows.Count Then
        linedata = "{" & linedata & "}"
    Else
        linedata = "{" & linedata & "},"
    End If

    jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
Next
linedata = "]}"
jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
jsonfile.Close


Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Is there a way to run it multiple times for multiple clients with a unique name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the line

```
Set jsonfile = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Satwant\Desktop\" & "MonthlyReport.json", True)
```

with

```
Dim s as string
s = inputbox("Enter Name you want to use")    
Set jsonfile = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Satwant\Desktop\" & s & ".json", True)
```

to get it to ask you for the file name each time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, is there a way for it to take the the name of the current sheet without asking the file name ?

Comment: you could suggest active sheet name to the user in this way: `s = inputbox("Enter Name you want to use", default:=activesheet.name)` or to get just sheet name use this `s = activesheet.name`.

Comment: @KazimierzJawor Thank very much, i will try that.

Comment: Thanks you guys i've got the idea on what to do.