# Parsing Excel to JSON, Handle the #N/A error

Tags: json, vba, string, parsing

I got an example from this publication to pass from excel to json, ([Is it possible in VBA convert Excel table to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100193/is-it-possible-in-vba-convert-excel-table-to-json)). I didnt change a lot of the code, actually I just add the
`RunTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:15") Application.OnTime RunTimer, "export_in_json_format"`command to keep it running every 15 seconds, the thing is when i got the #N/A value in one cell the code stop running cause the mismatch value, I already tried with one "solution" but instead of manage it and print it in the JSON file it crashed the program and change all the values #N/A for 0 in the code. Any idea, clue that could help me.

```
Option Explicit
Dim RunTimer As Date

Sub export_to_json()

Dim fs As Object
Dim jsonfile
Dim rangetoexport As Range
Dim rowcounter As Long
Dim columncounter As Long
Dim linedata As String

RunTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:15")

Application.OnTime RunTimer, "export_in_json_format"

' change range here
Set rangetoexport = Sheet1.Range("a1:s14")

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' change dir here

Set jsonfile = fs.CreateTextFile("D:\Upload JSON\json_to_firestore\files\" & "Notebook.json", True)
linedata = "["
jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
For rowcounter = 2 To rangetoexport.Rows.Count
    linedata = ""
    For columncounter = 1 To rangetoexport.Columns.Count
        linedata = linedata & """item" & rangetoexport.Cells(1, columncounter) & """" & ":" & """" & rangetoexport.Cells(rowcounter, columncounter) & """" & ","
    Next
    linedata = Left(linedata, Len(linedata) - 1)
    If rowcounter = rangetoexport.Rows.Count Then
        linedata = "{" & linedata & "}"
    Else
        linedata = "{" & linedata & "},"
    End If

    jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
Next
linedata = "]"
jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
jsonfile.Close

Set fs = Nothing

MsgBox "Update done.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check each cell value in case it's an error, then decide what to output instead.

```
Dim v

'...
'...
v = rangetoexport.Cells(rowcounter, columncounter).Value
linedata = linedata & """item" & rangetoexport.Cells(1, columncounter) & """" & ":" & _
           """" & IIf(iserror(v),"Error", v) & """" & ","
'...
'...
```